# Ajax updater not working in internet explorer

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer

I have a problem with ajax updater that i couldnt solve.
I have this code Servicii

It works perfectly in firefox but in internet explorer it does nothing.Also if i open the site from my harddrive it works but it only works for the link once then i have to reload the whole page...

Does anybody have an ideea on how to solve this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

I've had this exact problem.  I'm assuming that you've got a function which periodically makes a request to the server to fetch data then updates the page if that data has changed since the last time you made the request.

Internet Explorer will cache the results of Ajax calls to the same resource even if you tell it not to in your HTTP headers.  So if you make a request to `get_data?id=whatever` over and over again, IE will make the request once and then stop making it in the future and simply return the result of the first request.

The solution is to add a dummy parameter to the request string.  So first you request `get_data?id=whatever&ie_hack=0` then `get_data?id=whatever&ie_hack=1` etc.  This will stop IE from caching the results and force it to make the request each time, since it sees a different query string for each request.

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into a problem like this, not with caching but with race conditions. IE executed the render part of the function before the any data was returned. Here's the issue, and solution:

[Returned AJAX html breaks IE click events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424886/returned-ajax-html-breaks-ie-click-events)