# Ajax.Update doesn't work on IE 8

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, prototypejs

I have a login form and user can input usrname/password and click login button on this form to send a request to a server.

The login button calls a function named submitLoginFormIntoDivAndReload, and function submitLoginFormIntoDivAndReload calls another function named submitFormObjIntoDivAndReload.

Here are the details of the functions:

```
function submitLoginFormIntoDivAndReload(servletUrl, formObj, divId) {

//var formObj = document.getElementById(formId);
var shortUserName = formObj.shortusername.value;
alert("starting userName: " + shortUserName);
var organization = formObj.organization.value;
alert("organization: " + organization);
formObj.username.value = createLdapString(shortUserName, organization);
alert("ending userName: " + formObj.username.value);
var loggingInContent = "<table><tr><td width='600px' align='center'><p>logging in</p></td></tr></table>"
document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML = loggingInContent;

submitFormObjIntoDivAndReload(servletUrl, formObj, divId);

}

function submitFormObjIntoDivAndReload(url, formObj, divId) {
alert('Form object: ' + formObj);
alert('url: ' + url);
alert('divId: '+divId);
var myRequest = new Ajax.Updater(divId, url,
        {   method: 'post',
            parameters: Form.serialize(formObj),
            onSuccess: function(reponse) {
                window.location.reload();
            }
        });
alert("after update");
}
```

This code works perfectly on firefox. However, it doesn't work on IE.

On IE, i can get all alerts (for debugging). However, it seems that Ajax.Updater doesn't send a request to the server (I can't see any output on my server side).

on FireFox, i can get all alters too. And I can see Ajax.Updater does send a request to the server since i can see the expected output on my server side.

I searched the online and somebody said IE has a cache issue:
[Ajax updater not working in internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436432/ajax-updater-not-working-in-internet-explorer)
But it seems that the issue is only for the "GET" method, not for the "POST" method. I am using the "POST" method. I also added a fake input in the form, it still doesn't work.

Anybody has any idea? Thank you very much!

By the way, i am using prototype 1.5.1.

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Prototype?  1.7 has been out for a while now and has loads of improvements.

Comment: i changed to 1.7. Then it worked once on IE. But it doesn't work any more. Is this really cache issue?

Comment: Possibly.  Have you tried clearing your browser's cache before each attempt?  If you're able to, can you send cache-prevention headers with the server's response?  `Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate` and `Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT` ought to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Whether a POST or GET, your timing of the response is still going to be pretty close either way.  I'd say you're still experiencing a race condition that is continuing prior to a response from the server.

I'd look at [this link](http://wonko.com/post/how-to-prevent-yui-get-race-conditions) regarding preventing race conditions.  One of many solutions I have found says "set a loop up to check every ten milliseconds for a value, otherwise wait."

Comment: Is this a racing issue? I think the issue is the request never been sent out ( i can't see the expected out in my server side).